# MVC3 Tighlty Coupled View Casting Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tightly-coupled-code

this is my object

```
public class ProductContent
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public Location ProductLocation { get; set; }


    }
```

I have a view that is tightly coupled with Location object.

i have a view that is tightly coupled with ProductContent
in my productcontent view i do

```
@Html.Partial("../PartialViews/Location", Model.ProductLocation)
```

i get a error saying

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProductContent', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Location'.
```

I am passing Model.ProductLocation which is of type location but why does it still error off?

I am using MVC3 C# Razor

Comment: what is your @model directive in the view?

Comment: @model ProjectName.Models.DAO.Location

Comment: i guess `Model.ProductLocation` is null

Comment: @driushkin: the error message doesn't sound like a null error.

Comment: @Natasha Thapa: pls show the model declaration of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of asp.net mvc's `RenderPartial`. When you pass null as a model, it uses the model of parent view.

[ASP.NET MVC, strongly typed views, partial view parameters glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049027/asp-net-mvc-strongly-typed-views-partial-view-parameters-glitch)