# Shared View error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ..., but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.String"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a Newbie in Asp.net mvc 4 development, I have been developing for years in webforms and now I'm starting to develop in mvc, and I'm having some problems

In my new project I need to use a MarkdownEditor, I have encapsulated it in SharedView to facility the reuse of it across my views, (like create a Web user control in Webforms)

The code of the shared view with markdown editor is:

```
@model string

<div id="markdown-editor">
    <div class="wmd-panel">
        <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            @Html.TextArea("m_wmdinput", @Model, new { @class="wmd-input" })
        </div>
    <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
</div>
<script>
     ....
     ....
```

And this is an example where I use it as Render.PartialView.

```
@model MyProject.Models.PostIt

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>PostIt</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublishingDate)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishingDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishingDate)
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("MarkdownEditor", @Model.Content)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The model code is :

```
public class PostIt
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishingDate { get; set; }

    public PostIt()
    {
        ID = -1;
    }
}
```

And controller code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    PostIt postIt = new PostIt();

    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        postIt = new PostItBLL().GetByID(id.Value);
        if (postIt == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
    return View(postIt);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(PostIt postit)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         Save(postit);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(postit);
 }

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View(db.PostIt.ToList());
 }

 private void Save(PostIt postIt)
 {
     if (postIt.ID < 0)
     {
         new PostItBLL().Add(postIt);
     }
     else
     {
         new PostItBLL().Update(postIt);
     }
 }
```

The page loads correclty, but when I change som value and I click in save button I get the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.PostIt', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

Any clue about the error I'm making?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code of `class MyProject.Models.PostIt` and the relevant code of the `Controller.Action`?

Comment: @Silvermind I have update the question with controller and model code

Comment: and the code behind this `return RedirectToAction("Index");`?

Comment: @Silvermind I have updated controller code with all the code it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the Content property on the PostIt model is null. If you give Content a default value like string.Empty, the problem will not occur. You could do this:

```
@Html.Partial("MarkdownEditor", @Model.Content ?? string.Empty)
```

For an explanation, read the accepted answer for this question: [ASP.NET MVC, strongly typed views, partial view parameters glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049027/426840)