# MVC RenderPartial Shared Strongly Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, renderpartial

I have a Strongly Types Partial View that I am trying to render from another Partial View

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Days", Model.DaysOpen, new ViewDataDictionary()); }
```

I have been folling advice based on the below
[ASP.NET MVC, strongly typed views, partial view parameters glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049027/asp-net-mvc-strongly-typed-views-partial-view-parameters-glitch)

It allows me to create the parent(Centre) but does not create the Child (owned) Days entity.

Can anyone offer any advice

Details.cshtml

```
@model RCCMS.ObjectModel.Entities.Centre

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", Role = "form" }))
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the following errors:-")

<div id="HiddenFields">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RowVersion)
</div>

<fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address2, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address3, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address3, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address3, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Town, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Town, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Town, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.County, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Postcode, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Uprn, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Uprn, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Uprn, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lunch, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lunch, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lunch, "*")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VoluntaryContribution, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VoluntaryContribution, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VoluntaryContribution, "*")
        </div>
    </div>



    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Days", Model.DaysOpen, new ViewDataDictionary()); }


    <div class="col-md-offset-2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <input type="submit" id="cancel" name="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn"/>
    </div>

</fieldset>
}
```

And my Partial View (Days)

```
@model RCCMS.ObjectModel.Entities.Days

<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("Days Open", new {@class = "col-md-5 control-label"})
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Monday) Monday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Monday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tuesday) Tuesday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tuesday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Wednesday) Wednesday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Wednesday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Thursday) Thursday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Thursday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Friday) Friday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Friday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Saturday) Saturday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Saturday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Sunday) Sunday
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Sunday, "*")
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The create action of the CentreController

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        if (!Security.HasPemission(Permission.CanCreateCentres)) return View("AccessDenied");

        var model = new Centre();
        return (IsAjax()) ? (ActionResult)PartialView("Details", model) : View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What happens? null reference ? or no values?

Comment: Are you initialising your Model in your controller? Make sure     RCCMS.ObjectModel.Entities.Centre is not null.

Comment: Could you post the code of the HttpGet that passes the `Centre` model to this view? I want to make sure the `DaysOpen` property is not null.

Comment: I just get no values, the master data Centres is added, but days does not appear.  the create controller action has var model = new Centre(); as shown in the new edit, the code works fine if you replicate the PartialView Code in Details.cshtml

Comment: It seems that you are passing an empty model to your view?

Comment: Rather than `@{Html.RenderPartial(...)` try `@Html.Partial(...)` (no semi colon on end and no curly braces) - does this help?

Comment: Ive tried various methods of @{Html... and @Html... but no difference.  We have decided not to implement this idea at the moment and just duplicate the code but would still be interested in the result.