# Error with strongly-typed partial view when model is a property on a parent model and is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am getting the following exception on a call to `Html.RenderPartial`:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ChildClass' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ParentClass'.

These two classes are related this:

```
public class ChildClass { /* properties */ }

public class ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass ChildProperty { get; set; }

    /* other properties */
}
```

I have an instance of `ParentClass` where the value of `ChildProperty` is `null`.

I have two partial views, `ParentView` (`ViewUserControl<ParentClass>`) and `ChildView` (`ViewUserControl<ChildClass>`).

In the first view, I have the following...

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controls/ChildView.ascx", Model.ChildProperty); %>
```

This is the line that is throwing the exception listed at the top of this post.

I have verified correct functionality if `ChildProperty` is not null. Why does MVC think that a null value of this property is of the parent type?

I can workaround this issue by adding code that only renders the `ChildView` if `ChildProperty` is not null, but this half defeats the point of having the view.

Comment: I can't explain the error message, but the best solution to these types of problems is to apply the **Null Object pattern** : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the answer here: [renderpartial with null model gets passed the wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650393/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-with-null-model-gets-passed-the-wrong-type/713921#713921)

If it works, your fix should look like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controls/ChildView.ascx", Model.ChildProperty, 
      new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
```