# Html helper DropDownList with nullable model throws ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Model

```
namespace Models
{
    public class PartialTestModel
    {
        public int? NullableProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works fine

```
<div class="highlight1">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NullableProp, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), Model.NullableProp), "-- Select one --")
</div>
```

However if a partial view is created for this property

```
@model System.Int32?

<div class="highlight1">
    Model's value is

    @if (@Model.HasValue)
    {
        @Model.ToString()
    }
    else
    { 
        <text>Null</text>
    }

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), Model), "-- Select one --")
</div>
```

It throws an error

```
Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name

[ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +396232
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel) +14
```

The View renders the partial as

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialTest", Model.NullableProp, new ViewDataDictionary())
```

`new ViewDataDictionary()` is added as per the answer in [asp.net mvc renderpartial with null model gets passed the wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650393/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-with-null-model-gets-passed-the-wrong-type/713921#713921). Without this incorrect model is seen in the partial view when the property value is null. When the property values are not null it can be used

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialTest", Model.NullableProp)
```

but still results in the same error as pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.DropDownListFor(m => m, ...` uses the lambda expression to create the input's name.  However, `m => m` doesn't contain a property, so there's no name.

It might work if you instead use `m => m.Value`, because since this is a lambda expression, it might not actually be executed.