# How do I invoke a partial view with “null” for its model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Suppose I have a partial view called `UserDetails` whose `@model` clause is set to a model class called `User`.

Now suppose I have another model class that looks something like this:

```
public sealed class SpecialModel
{
    public User SpecialUser;
    public ... // other stuff
}
```

Inside a view for the `SpecialModel`, I want to invoke my partial view mentioned above:

```
@model MyProject.Models.SpecialModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "..."; }
<div class='user'>@Html.Partial("UserDetails", Model.SpecialUser)</div>
```

This works just fine *if the user is not `null`*. However, if the user is `null`, I get this exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.SpecialModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.User'.

Clearly, the exception message is lying. How do I fix this properly so that I can pass `null` normally?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of

```
@Html.Partial("UserDetails", Model.SpecialUser)
```

write the more verbose

```
@Html.Partial("UserDetails", new ViewDataDictionary(Model.SpecialUser))
```

That makes this specific scenario work.

However, it has a downside: it clears all information passed from the controller. In particular, it clears all the validation information; if you are posting some data and you want to display a validation error message inside that partial view, you can’t use this technique.

Comment: The following solution  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12037580/649497) overcomes the downside!

Comment: This no longer works for dotnet core 2 / mvc 2.0.3. [But I've found a solution that does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650393/renderpartial-with-null-model-gets-passed-the-wrong-type#comment85738016_713921)

Comment: Yea, it clears away all the validation information and your ViewBag. "Other than that, how did you like the play, Mrs. Lincoln?"