# Partial View model doesn't resolve

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial

I have a model A which has a property which is of another model type, B.  I have a view which is tied to A.  I want to add a partial view  to to A which takes a model of type B.  This is my code

```
public class ModelA
{
    public bool Prop1 {get;set;}
    public bool Prop2 {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<int, string> Prop3{get; set;}
    public int Prop4 {get; set;}
    public ModelB Prop5 { get; set; }


    public ModelA ()
    {
        Prop5 = null;

       ... more code ...
    }
}

//This view is tied to ModelA
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateReport", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   some markup
}

//this is the problem
@Html.Partial("FileLinks",  Model.Prop5) //This line throws an error
```

> Error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ModelA', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ModelB'

The line works if i change it to `@Html.Partial("FileLinks", new ModelB())`

Why doesn't the original code work?  The property is of type ModelB.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Update:  I forgot to add some code from the Controller

m.FileLinks = new ModelB()
return View("Index", m)

So the model is not null

Comment: Post the FileLinks View please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i think happening here is that

when you render a partial view like this the `ViewDataDictionary` and the Views Context is passed to the partial view
so when the `ModelB` is null then the `ViewDataDictionary<TModel>` isnt changed and at runtime teh MVC engine cannot determine the type of model from a `null` value.

Comment: This makes sense.  I forgot to add something else  , in the controller action above, i initialize  initalize FileLinks like so FileLinks = new ModelB() then return the view with that model.Sp prop5 is no longer null when the view is returned.  Code: m.FileLines = new ModelB(); return View("Index", m)

Comment: I do think this is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this and I get the same error if Prop5 is null.  If I initialize Prop5 to a new ModelB then it works.

The error is not very clear (you would think this would throw a NullReferenceException).

I also tried this:

```
@Html.Parial("FileLinks",null)
```

and the same error occurs.  This seems to be the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650393/renderpartial-with-null-model-gets-passed-the-wrong-type)